# Java repeating decimal in simple equation

Tags: java

I am doing a school assignment in which I solve an equation involving coordinates in a circle (r^2 = x^2 + y^2) were r = 1, and you increment through x values solving for y. I am getting a repeating decimals even though I only incrementing in tenths. I have no idea why and have tried it in a few different ways. Here is the code.

```
    double r = 1;
    double rSqr;
    double x = 1;
    double xSqr;
    double y;
    double ySqr;
    double inc = 0.1;
    int count = 0;
    while(x > -r)
    {
        x = r - (count * inc);
        rSqr = Math.pow(r, 2);
        xSqr = Math.pow(x, 2);
        ySqr = rSqr - xSqr;
        y = Math.sqrt(ySqr);
        count++;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
```

and the output is this

```
1.0 0.0
0.9 0.4358898943540673
0.8 0.5999999999999999
0.7 0.714142842854285
0.6 0.8
0.5 0.8660254037844386
0.3999999999999999 0.9165151389911681
0.29999999999999993 0.9539392014169457
0.19999999999999996 0.9797958971132712
0.09999999999999998 0.99498743710662
0.0 1.0
-0.10000000000000009 0.99498743710662
-0.20000000000000018 0.9797958971132712
-0.30000000000000004 0.9539392014169457
-0.40000000000000013 0.9165151389911679
-0.5 0.8660254037844386
-0.6000000000000001 0.7999999999999999
-0.7000000000000002 0.7141428428542849
-0.8 0.5999999999999999
-0.9000000000000001 0.43588989435406705
-1.0 0.0
```

Comment: What is the desired output? What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `double` is imprecise. It uses 64 bits to represent decimal numbers; some bits are used for the numeric part, and some for the exponent, but many seemingly simple decimal numbers can not be accurately represented in this way, for example `0.1`. See [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more.

One way around the problem is to display the number using `DecimalFormat`, which can round the number for presentation purposes. Here's some example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
    double d = 1 - .9; // one way to get a repeating decimal floating point number 
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));
}
```

Output:

```
0.09999999999999998
0.100
```

Comment: @TylerLall Exactly - this is a "rendering" issue, not a mathematical one. You will encounter this many times in your career - always try to separate the concerns of the "do it" code for the "show it" code, and don't compromise or complicate the "do it" code because some guy in marketing wants the output to look a certain way.

Comment: lol thanks. Also thanks for explaining it was a rendering issue not a math one.

Comment: Strictly speaking, though, it IS a math issue.  Or can be, depending on your requirements.  I've had a loop fail to iterate the expected number of times because 0.1 isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point representation.

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) as datatype instead of `double` to solve your problem.
But take care as `BigDecimal` is `immutable`.

```
        BigDecimal r = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal rSqr;
        BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal xSqr;
        BigDecimal y;
        BigDecimal ySqr;
        BigDecimal inc = new BigDecimal("0.1");
        int count = 0;

        while(x.compareTo(r.negate())>0)
        {
        // i'll let you fill in this part
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not gotten to BigDecimal yet so I will do some reading up on it.